# Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 failed to access/open camera on windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, camera

I am using Google Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit), whenever i am trying to access camera (USB2.0 HB UVC Webcam (04f2:b57a)) on google meet not able to open/access in google chrome. I tried with  firefox browser thats work fine there. I have already uninstall and reinstall google chrome but no luck. How to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem degraded google chrome version  83.0.4103.97 to  81.0.4044.92. And download the older version from [here](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php)

Comment: For me it didn't work. I use Dell notebook, I resolved the problem by installing optional driver upgrades in Dell Command Update.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2062037?hl=en&msgid=15445715)

**Add a command-line switch (CLS) to the desktop shortcut of Chrome:**

1. [Completely close Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2062037?hl=en&msgid=15445715) (see bottom)
2. right-click the desktop icon of Chrome
3. click 'properties'
4. insert the CLS at the right end of the target field (also copy the leading space):

   `--enable-features=RunVideoCaptureServiceInBrowserProcess`
5. click the "OK" button

[image]

**​How to close Chrome completely:**

1. close all windows of Chrome
2. open the Windows Task Manager [ctrl + shift + esc]
3. if you see any open Chrome processes (chrome.exe), end them

Comment: No luck, still camera is getting offed. Getting error  "camera failed: USB2.0 HB UVC Webcam (04f2:b57a)"